# pagination/prev and next page links not showing

Tags: jquery, html

```
$('a.prev, a.next').click(function(){
var a = $(this),
    current = $('#pagin li a.current'),
    page = parseInt(current.text());
if (a.hasClass('prev')) {
    page--;
    if (page < 1) page = 1;
} else if (a.hasClass('next')) {
    page++;
    if (page > pageCount) page = pageCount;
}
$('.page:eq(' + (page - 1) + ')').click();
});
```

This not working. Please help me..

How to add next and previous buttons in this code.

Please see Js fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/jfm9y/609/

Comment: `pageCount is not defined`

Comment: `.page` does not exist on your fiddle, not that it's the core issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You needed to declare the pageCount of the content.

Working example : http://jsfiddle.net/jfm9y/611/

```
pageSize = 1;
pageCount = $(".content").length;

showPage = function(page) {
    $(".content").hide();
    $(".content").each(function(n) {
        if (n >= pageSize * (page - 1) && n < pageSize * page)
            $(this).show();
    });        
}

showPage(1);

$("#pagin li a").click(function() {
    $("#pagin li a").removeClass("current");
    $(this).addClass("current");
    showPage(parseInt($(this).text())) 
});
    $('a.prev, a.next').click(function(){
    var a = $(this),
        current = $('#pagin li a.current'),
        page = parseInt(current.text());
        console.log(page);
    if (a.hasClass('prev')) {
        page--;
        if (page < 1) page = 1;
    } else if (a.hasClass('next')) {
        page++;
        if (page > pageCount) page = pageCount;
    }

    $($('#pagin li a')[page- 1]).click();
});
```